# convergence of an alternating complex series (excercise $10.20.41$ in Tom Apostol's calculus)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I would like to solve exercise $10.20.41$:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (z-1)^n}{n}$.

We can make a substitution $z-1 = re^{i \theta}$, and then it is easy to show that as long as $r < 1$, the series converges. So let's focus on the case $r=1$. Then we have

$s_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n e^{in\theta}}{n}$.

From theorem $10.19$, we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{in\theta}$ is bounded, as long as $\theta \ne 2k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer.

Using a similar method, we can prove that $t_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{2in\theta} = i \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\cos \theta} e^{i(n+1)\theta}$, for $e^{i\theta} \ne -1$:

$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k x^k = x \frac{x^n - 1}{x + 1}$, for $x \ne -1$

For $x = e^{2 \theta i} \ne -1$, we have

$t_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{2in\theta} = e^{2i\theta} \frac{e^{2i\theta n} - 1}{e^{2i\theta} + 1} = i e^{i(n+1)\theta}\frac{\sin(n \theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$

That makes it bounded, and then we can apply Dirichlet's test to prove that $s_n$ also converges for $z-1 \ne -1$.

I wanted to check here if the alternating complex sum is really as I found it (and it could be useful for posterity).

I couldn't find the answer on approach zero and wolfram alpha, so if you think I should be able to find it, please post the search link pointing to the answer, so I can learn how to do it in future.

Thanks!

Comment: Your work looks fine to me, but you're "sloppy" when writing $t_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty...$ as you really meant the partial sum, and the letter '$n$' is overloaded

Comment: @FShrike I agree I'm still new to the field and the annotation, so it seems sloppy...